# Format of points in Polyline shapes in a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, polyline-creation

I am have been asked to write some code that looks at a SHP file that contains a load of Polyline shapes that are used to represent parking areas in a British council's area. I've created a C# program to read the data, but I have noted a number of things that don't seem to make sense to me so I wondered if anyone would be able to shine some light on it (I am not a GIS guy)...

Looking at the points on a Polyline shape, it seems as though the points start with extreme numbers for the X and Y coordinates ( -1.4600101262233409E+239 and -8.5448987622302689E-70 for instance) followed by more sensible figures like 185747.93946064217 which seems to bear a relationship to the GPS position (-0.18ish).

Am I right in thinking that this positional data is actually subject to some sort of base box, and if so, where are it's settings stored? Also, how do we set the type of coordinates used?

Comment: I you haven't already I suggest you ti read this https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf, it may give you some answer and a better understanding of shapefile

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you tell us which GIS software you are using and the approximate location in Britain that the data is for?

Comment: The data is for Barnet, and I have had to write my own C# code to read the data... I suspect the files are "valid" because I have seen them in an online tool producing mapping data, but exposing the data using the online tool only shows a single point on a line - and of course a line with a single point is not that helpful.

Comment: For starters the sensible figure you gave of 185747 makes sense as a Y coordinate for Barnet in the British National Grid coordinate system

Comment: Shapefiles contain a header with both little-endian and big-endian encoded values, and a mix of long integers and doubles, as described in the Shapefile Specification. All non-point file types have a BND box early in the structure, with an integer to specify the number of parts. Polyline and polygon shapes include the number of vertices per part. The spec does *not* describe the `.prj` file, but there are other documents to describe how to parse that.

Comment: Thanks for that folks... I am going to look at the British National Grid Coordinate System and see where that can lead me...